# Each versus every (again...)

Tags: determiners

I know that there are tons of threads on "each" vs. "every" in this site and grammar sites. I have already gone through many of them. However, I still cannot come up with an answer when I am using scientific statements that are both generalising and refering to particular instances. Should I use "each" or "every", and why? Or are both correct? For example:

> Each solar eruption sends radiation into space.

> Every solar eruption sends radiation into space.

Comment: Without more context it's not possible to answer.  In context you might prefer the one or the other, but both are correct, with only nuanced difference.

Comment: It's a question of perspective, and what you will say about them before and after.

Answer (score 2):

"Every" can be used without any limits, whereas "each" can only be used when referring to a specific or limited set, however large.

For example, you might say "*every child should have an education*" which would be a blanket statement about all children, everywhere - even those not yet born. It is (sadly) not true to say that every child *does* receive an education. However, if you were talking about a specific set of children that you know were educated, you could say of that set "*each child received an education*".

Likewise with your example, if emitting radiation is true of all solar eruptions - even ones that have not been observed, and in stars that have not been discovered - and your intention is to make a blanket statement about solar eruptions then you should use 'every'. But, if you were speaking about the results of a series of observations of solar eruptions, either in one star or among many, you could refer to 'each of them', meaning each of the eruptions you observed.

Comment: @rajesun Well, you'll notice that, at the moment, moon78's answer has been flagged in the comments by a moderation bot as requiring improvement. If it doesn't improve, it will be recommended for deletion. They have a reputation of 51, I have a reputation of 83,700. That doesn't mean I'm infallible but it's worth noting. In fairness, moon78's answer isn't *wrong* but only covers one very specific type of context - where you could use either word. Your question was one 'versus' the other, which is why I explained when and why you should use one over the other. Moon78 does not address this.

Comment: @rajesun If you think that their explanation answers your question then, by all means, take their advice. Remember, I didn't say they were wrong - just that it has a very narrow focus. Their advice would not apply to the examples I gave, and I do not think it applies to yours either. I'm not going to fight over the accepted answer.

Comment: @rajesun My answer is neither an 'opinion' nor a 'theory'. It does not contradict the other answer - I have just attempted to better explain the difference using examples. I have absolutely no interest in chasing your 50 bounty points when I already have 83,717 reputation points. I'd prefer to lose 50 points for a correct answer that others thought was wrong than chase points by telling you what you want to hear. If you want to give them to Moon78 it will be a big help to them as they only have 59 points because this is literally their first answer on this site, ever.

Comment: -1 "*'each' can only be used when referring to a specific or limited set*" I disagree. Consider: "*Each natural number has a successor.*" here the set referred to is literally infinite, but I find the sentence to be perfectly acceptable (and mathematically true).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emphasize the individuality of the members of a group, use "each".

If you want to refer to the constituents of a group as a whole, use "every".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question of one word 'versus' the other. You have only covered a very specific situation where one could use either word and the subtle inference that could be implied by each. There are clear situations where one word should not be used.

Comment: While there are cases where only one of "each" and "every" should be used, the sentences inn the question are not among those cases, and such cases are in my view rare. I prefer this answer to the other. It is at least correct if not complete.